# like query in Appcelerator cloud service for android sdk

Tags: java, android, appcelerator

am using appcelerator cloud services for android sdk. I've audio files uploaded on the ACS.Now i want to search those audio file with "Like" query which is used in SQL.
for example

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country LIKE '%land%';
```

and the result would be like

```
Ireland
finland
poland
```

i'v searched ACS documentation but couldn't find anything that like query at all.
any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

it can not be done.

the best you can do is a regex query OR a full text query. With the regex query it will only perform a "starts with" not a contains query... see documentation here

http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/guide/search_query